# dimension of kernel of differential operator restricted to polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

I have the differential operator:
$$\frac{d}{dx} +2x \cdot$$
operating on $P$, the polynomials.
I want to know the dimension of the kernel of $\frac{d}{dx} +2x\cdot$.

My argument is that the dimesnion is zero because solving
$$\frac{dy}{dx} +2xy=0$$
produces 
$$y(x) = Ae^{-x^2}$$
which is clearly not in $P$.
But, my friend argues that since we can write
$$e^{-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}$$
the solution *is* in $P$, and hence dimension is 1. I'm not comfortable with this argument, but I can't explain why.
Is my friend wrong? Why or why not?

Comment: Your friend is wrong. He is claiming that any analytic function is a polynomial, which makes no sense. Polynomials are, by definition, of finite degree. My counter-question is: are you sure that the operator is not $y\mapsto \frac{d}{dx}y+2x$? (without the $y$ at the very end?)

Comment: Thanks, I felt it was related to infinity but didn't know what I could cite to demonstrate that.

Comment: The operator is copied exactly from the worksheet

Comment: That the operator is written like that is not equivalent to saying that it acts as you say. But yes, it as well might. Is it written that the operator is linear? Because if so, then my interpretation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the operator to any non-trivial polynomial with degree $n$, then the result will have degree $n+1$ by the second term.

Only the zero polynomial thus results in the zero polynomial.